# R - Normalising data of a matrix - Double for loop

Tags: r, loops, double, normalization

I would like to normalise the data that are in a data frame called "VI9A_mining". 
Each column of my data frame represents a element; and each line represents the concentration of the given element.
For each concentration of a given element, I would like to withdrow the mean concentration of that element. 
So if I have :

```
Ca Zr K                     Ca  Zr  K
2  14 4  ==> i would like : -3  4   1
8  10 5                      3  0   2
5  6  0                      0  -4  -3
```

Here is what I tried:

```
VI9A_mn=matrix(nrow=21,ncol=length(nom_mining)) #VI9A_mn is the output matrix
for (j in nom_mining){   #nom_mining is a vector with all the names of the columns of VI9A_mining
  for (i in VI9A_mining){
    VI9A_mn(i,j)=VI9A_mining(i,j)-mean(VI9A_mining(j))
  }
}
```

So I'd like a loop that works all the lines (i) in each columns (j).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sapply()` with an anonymous function on your *numeric columns*:

```
num_cols <- sapply(df, is.numeric) # Find numeric columns
df[,num_cols] <- sapply(df[,num_cols], function(x) x-mean(x)) # Apply function
```

Comment: Thanks but I have non-numeric columns in my data frame on which I don't want to apply that operation. So i'm not shure if sapply can work here?

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Comment: You may want to look at the scale function.  It will preform the same operation as x-mean(x) along with an option to normalize based on the standard deviation.